# How to get the (x,y,z) value of HTC vive Gyroscope in real-time?

Tags: viewport, gyroscope, htc-vive

have you met this problem?I want to get the X,Y,Z values from **htc vive HMD** in real-time,but i don't know how to do it.I guess whether the htc vive SDK has the special interface for developer?Could you please give me some help?thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion is only valid if Unity is being used.
Not sure about getting the coordinates from the HMD, but you can attach a script that detects the position of the GameObject.

```
this.transform.localPosition.x
this.transform.localPosition.y
this.transform.localPosition.z
```

These are read only values.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The SteamVR SDK [doesn't seem to expose the raw values of the IMU](https://steamcommunity.com/app/358720/discussions/0/451848855023434508/)  (inertial measurement unit) to developers. Possible workarounds:

- Using the velocity of the HMD via the SteamVR SKD [GetDeviceToAbsoluteTrackingPose](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/wiki/IVRSystem::GetDeviceToAbsoluteTrackingPose)
- Calculate the velocity of the HMD [manually](https://answers.unity.com/questions/38429/how-can-i-calculate-velocity-without-using-rigidbo.html) or by adding a [RigidBody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html) component to the main camera (Camera (eye))